# Intersection of spaces with Schauder basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, schauder-basis

Let $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a basic sequence in $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $V_m =\overline{\operatorname{span}} \{v_n\}_{n \geq m} $

Let $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a basic sequence in $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $U_m =\overline{\operatorname{span}} \{u_n\}_{n \geq m} $

Let $W_m = V_m + U_m$

I would like to know if it is true that

$$
\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty
W_m
= 
\{0\}
$$

Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMitra I don't understand your comment

Comment: Sorry, I goofed.

Comment: @DavidMitra, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(e_n)$ be the standard unit vectors in $\ell_2$.

Choose $(\alpha_n)\in\ell_2$  with $\alpha_n\ne0 $ for each $n$ to have  $\ell_2$ norm so small that the sequence 
$$e_1,\ \alpha_1 e_1+e_2,\ \alpha_2 e_1+e_3,\ \ldots$$ is  basic (you can do this using perturbation results for basic sequences). Take this to be $(v_n)$ and take $(u_n)$ to be $(e_n)$ . Then $e_1\in  W_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: again I don't understand your answer, $\alpha_n \in \ell^2$ so it is a vector, well, what do you mean when you write $\alpha_1e_1$?

Comment: $(\alpha_n)$ is the vector. $\alpha_1$ is its first coordinate. So, $\alpha_1e_1=(\alpha_1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: ok thanks for your clarification @DavidMitra